# common way to store single keys in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Currently I have a collection of keys in my ruby code, which stored inside hash object. And when I add new element, I just check if that key already exist, if not then add new key to my collection with some default value, like this:

```
unless @issues.has_key?(issue_id)
   @issues[issue_id] = '';
end
```

But I don't like this method. Is it possible to make that better, without using unnecessary value.

Comment: How do you add a new element ? If you can supply both key & value I see no point in the question. If you just ask for some value for undefined keys, just pass to `Hash` constructor an object or a block. Just like `@issues = Hash.new('')` and then `@issues[:unexisting] == ''` .

Comment: hash store key and value. I do not have value, I need to stores only the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use a [`Set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html).

Sets are a collection of unique objects (no repeats).

```
# @issues = Set.new

unless @issues.include?(issue_id)
  @issues << issue_id
end
```

They keys of a hash are, in fact, a set (although not necessarily implemented via the Set class).

**[Edit]** Note that if you are storing complex objects (e.g. not builtins such as numbers, strings, symbols, etc.) you'll need to override both the [`hash` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-hash) and the [`eql?` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) so that they can be hashed properly.  The same goes if you are using complex objects as keys for hashing.

```
class Foo
  attr_read :name, :hash
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @hash = name.hash
  end
  def eql?(o)
    o.is_a?(Foo) && (o.name == self.name)
  end
end

s = Set.new
s << Foo.new("Foo!")
s << Foo.new("Foo!")
s.to_a # => [ #<Foo:0x0123 @name="Foo!"> ]
```

Comment: Thanks to you =) This is the perfect choice for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default value for hash

```
h = Hash.new("")
h[issue_id] => ""
```

Comment: I know, it's the way I do it (it's mentions in the question by the way) But I don't like such approach.

Comment: You said 'add new key to my collection with some default value', but my decision is about define default value once and nothing more.

Comment: hm, and if I do that, and then decide to add new key which will be the syntax?

Comment: Usually, keeping empty keys in hash means that the algorithm can be redesigned, just try to rethink your decision.